# slept for 50 minutes or had been sleeping for 50 minutes

Tags: past-tense, past-simple, past-perfect-continuous

"I went to my cousin's room and I slept on the couch there for 50 minutes and then my aunt woke me up"
or
"I went to my cousin's room and I had been sleeping on the couch there for 50 minutes and then my aunt woke me up"

Which is correct and why and is the tense used here correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both sentences are grammatically *correct* but they are very long.  I'd suggest using "when" instead of "and then" to join the last two clauses.

Two sentences:

> I went to my cousin's room **and** slept on the couch [there]. **I'd been sleeping** for 50 minutes **when** my aunt woke me up.

The [Past Perfect Continuous](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/past-perfect-continuous-i-had-been-working) is used appropriately because the act of *sleeping* was ongoing/in progress *before* being woken up.

To make the sentence shorter you can replace "and" with a comma, as suggested by @Stefan, and omit the subject pronoun implicit in the second clause.

One sentence:

> I went to my cousin's room, **slept** on the couch for 50 minutes **then** my aunt woke me up.

The [Past Simple](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/past-perfect-simple-or-past-simple) is appropriate because the sequence of events is clear: (1) he/she went into the cousin's room (2) slept (3) was woken up by their aunt.

Comment: I disagree that both are correct. _Had been sleeping_ requires **when** _my aunt woke me_.

Comment: @KateBunting I think you're right. I've modified my answer.

Comment: Or "I had been sleeping on the couch in my cousin's room for 50 minutes when my aunt woke me up" or "My aunt woke me up after I had been sleeping on the couch in my cousin's room for 50 minutes." In your one sentence re-write, there should be a comma after "50 minutes", and I think "until" works better than "then", to more strongly convey that action was interrupted.

Comment: @Acccumulation Yes, all valid suggestions because there's more than one way to skin a cat; however, I preferred to keep as close as possible to the original.

Comment: @KateBunting - They're both structurally/gramatically correct, but convey different meanings.  The "I slept [x minutes] ... and then my aunt woke me up" version  suggests that the sleep was completed independently of the aunt coming in to perform the wake-up.  While the "I had been sleeping [x minutes] ... and then my aunt woke me up" version suggests that the sleep was still in progress and would have continued if not for the aunt coming to perform the wake-up. I'd assume the latter is the intended meaning. Any yes, **when** works much better there.

Comment: Your second examples needs an "and" or ",and". > "I went to my cousin's room, slept on the couch for 50 minutes, and then my aunt woke me up." Alternatively, > "I went to my cousin's room, and slept on the couch for 50 minutes. Then my aunt woke me up."

Comment: Why does the length matter? The long version with the simple past sounds perfectly natural to me (native speaker), though only informally.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Your edit didn't address Kate's comment, or am I missing something?

Comment: @wjandrea  You can look at the edit history, I slightly changed the second sentence after Kate's comment.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yeah, I looked at it, but I don't see the difference. Kate said "they're not both correct" and after the edit it says "they're both correct". I'm only talking about the first sentence, myself.

Comment: The first sentence in my answer is grammatical. It didn't need changing. I interpreted her comment as saying "when" is needed with the Past Perfect. But if she disagrees that the OP's two original versions are not both grammatical then I disagree.

Comment: I'm not saying it's not grammatical; I'm only talking about the meaning. If "when" is needed with the past perfect, then both sentences *aren't* grammatically correct; only the first one is.

Comment: @wjandrea the OP's original sentences did not use "when" as a relative pronoun, I did in *both* of my sentences. I don't want to get involved in a long discussion over something that's quite trivial. Feel free to post an answer and explain in more detail.

Comment: omg sorry, I was looking at the wrong edit and that got me confused which "sentence" you were referring to. I was looking at revision 2 instead of 4. But still I don't see how revision 4 reflects Kate's comment. Let me re-explain: Kate said "I disagree that both are correct." You said "I think you're right", but after the edit, your answer still says "Both are correct".

Answer (score 5):

> I went to my cousin's room and I slept on the couch there for 50 minutes and then my aunt woke me up

That's ok. A sequence of actions, so you can use simple past. Replacing the "and I" by a comma would make it sound better.

> I went to my cousin's room and I had been sleeping on the couch there for 50 minutes and then my aunt woke me up

"And then" sound strange in this sentence because "had been sleeping" does not describe a completed action but your state at a certain point in time. The reader expects to read what point in time you are referring to, e.g. "when my aunt woke me up". By writing "and then my aunt woke me up", the "had been sleeping" is left hanging in the air, at least to my ears.